# Getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException when the property is present

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain class which has been working alright. But now I added a `Long` property and it all goes south from there.

This is the Accident domain class definition:

```
class Accident {

    String fullDescription
    Date dateFrom
    Date dateTo
    Long lastUpdated

    Address address
    GpsPosition gpsPosition
    String providerDescription
    String link

    static constraints = {
        address nullable: true
        gpsPosition nullable: true
        providerDescription nullable: true
        link nullable: true
        fullDescription maxSize: 1024
        lastUpdated nullable: true
    }
}
```

And this is where I get the error:

```
@Transactional
class DatabaseCleanupService {

    static final long timeNotUpdatedToDelete = 1 * 1000 // milliseconds

    void cleanupDatabase() {
        Accident accident

        Accident.each {
            /*ERROR AT THIS LINE*/ if (System.currentTimeMillis() - it.lastUpdated > timeNotUpdatedToDelete) { 
              // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I can access the property from other parts of the code, I successfully print debug info, but at this point, it just crashes. What is wrong with it?

---

Edit: The error message says this:

*No such property: `lastUpdated` for class: `com.quarky.nehodyprahaserver.Accident` Possible solutions: lastUpdated*

Comment: Dont you need: `Accident.list().each`

Comment: God. Dammit. You can write it 100x, but still fail on the 101st time. Thanks! Post an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Done ;-)  Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a list of Accidents first, changing:

```
    Accident.each {
```

to

```
    Accident.list().each {
```

Should fix it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending how many `Accident` instances there are in your database, it would probably be significantly more efficient to do the filtering by date at the database level rather than fetching the entire table into Groovy objects every time and filtering post-hoc:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

@Transactional
class DatabaseCleanupService {

    static final long timeNotUpdatedToDelete = 1 * 1000 // milliseconds

    void cleanupDatabase() {
        use(TimeCategory) {
            Accident.findAllByLastUpdatedLessThan(
              timeNotUpdatedToDelete.milliseconds.ago).each {

                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(or just inline the constant as `1.second.ago` - this looks wrong when you read it as English "last updated less than one second ago" but it is correct, as `LessThan` means "earlier than" when applied to `Date` objects)

Comment: tbh I am unfamiliar with this method. the `findAllByLastUpdatedLessThan` is Groovy's auto-injected (?) method? How does it determine when was the last time the element was updated? Does it keep a hidden field that is set on each .save(), or am I completely wrong? :D

Comment: The `findAllBy...` method is a [dynamic finder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) that gets translated into an SQL query.  And the `lastUpdated` property is automatically maintained by hibernate (see the last paragraph of [the user guide section on "events and auto-timestamping"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping))

Comment: @MartinMelka ... ah, sorry, I see that your `lastUpdated` property is _not_ in fact the conventional auto-updated one - you should consider changing its type to `java.util.Date` to take advantage of this feature, or name it something else if you don't want it to be mistaken for the auto timestamp.

Comment: Didn't know about the findAllBy methods. They are awesome! If I understand it correctly, simply having `Date lastUpdated` attribute inside a domain class is enough to have it automatically filled by Hibernate?

Comment: @MartinMelka yes, a `Date lastUpdated` property will be kept up to date automatically with the time the object was most recently saved to the database (for any reason, whether an explicit `.save()` or an implicit dirty check).